# Why do I get free(): double free detected in tcache 2 and aborted (core dumped)*

Tags: c, coredump, double-free

I am writing code to get the blood type for each generation. And it has a function, which frees the person and his ancestors, but I got those two errors:
*free(): double free detected in tcache 2;
Aborted (core dumped)*.
Below is the code to free the family. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

> ```
> void free_family(person *p)
> {
>     // Handle base case: input of NULL
>     for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
>     {
>         // do not free NULL pointer
>         if (p == NULL)
>         {
>             continue;
>         }
>         person *cursor = p -> parents[i];
>         person *tmp = cursor;
>         while (cursor != NULL)
>         {
>             //Free parents
>             cursor = cursor -> parents[i];
>             free(tmp);
>             tmp = cursor;
>         }
>         // Free child
>         free(cursor);
>         free(p);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but your code should return and not enter the for loop if p is NULL.

Comment: One thing that doesn't make sense is the call `free(cursor)` after the loop.  The loop only exits when `cursor` is `NULL`, so this call is equivalent to `free(NULL)`, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't checked all your code, however:

Your loop iterates twice. Each time, it calls `free(p)` which doesn't change between iterations.

A possible fix may be to move the call to be outside of the loop.